# How to insert new row in between 2 rows in existing excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I want to use an existing `HSSFWorkBook` (Apache POI) and insert new rows in between two existing  rows with new values.I tried with `sheet.shiftRows(n1, n2, n3)`, but it overwrites after shifting the values. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual way to do it is to shift all your other rows down, then write your new data into the rows that were left behind.

So, if you wanted to add in two rows between rows 14 and 15, shift rows from 15 onwards down by two, then write your new values into rows 15 and 16. (Your old row 15 would then be row 17)

Comment: This approach works, though the shifted rows do not keep their properties(e.g. height, font size etc.)